GNOME style is broken
Since I changed the graphic driver on my Ubuntu 24.04 the GNOME style is completely broken. I rolled back the NVIDIA driver to Nouveau and tried to apply the style as shown in the screenshot, but nothing works.
I'm running gnome 46 on X11, but I have the same behavior with Wayland
Here are some examples.
Appearance setting:

Display settings:

Edit:

If I run gnome 47 through a distrobox the issue remain.
If I create a new user the appearance is back to normal. So is there a way to "reset" my user session parameters?

